# Why I Can't get string from fragment arguments?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to get string from fragment  but I received  that it as null .
How can I solve it

```
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("Test","");
    new TestFragment().setArguments(bundle);
```

Comment: Can you please add more code here? I see that you are adding string as null in this line ... bundle.putString("Test","");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending data in correct way, please use below code for getting it on your TestFragment

```
if (getArguments() != null) {
            String test = getArguments().getString("Test");
        }
```